# form not saving to database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, currency, bigdecimal

I currently have a form:

```
<%= f.label(:price) %> <br/>
<%= f.text_field(:price, :value => number_to_currency(@object.price)) %>
```

I changed my migration from using float to using decimal:

```
change_column :object, :price, :decimal, :precision => 5, :scale => 2
```

On my view, I called it using:

```
<%= @object.price %>
```

For some reason, whenever I make a change to the form or in the console, it never saves the value and keeps it at $0.00 regardless of what i change it to.  In the view, it always shows up as '0.0'.  I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a table named `object` or `objects` or is this just an example?

If not, check your price column to make sure the migration worked properly.

If you do have a proper column type in your table, check to see if you're using `attr_accessible` in the `Object` class (and that `price` is included).

Also, if you are using `Object` as your class name, you may have some other issues here and I'd advise against it.

**EDIT** 
`number_to_currency`may prepend a $ in front of your cost, make sure you're entering your price without any currency before it or else I believe this would also result in 0.0 (can't parse decimal '$123.00', but can parse '123.00'

Comment: Hi Kristian, Thank you.  Object was just an example.  I did have attr_accessible with price included.  It was because of the $ sign in front of my price that as you mentioned, can't be parsed.  When I enter it without the dollar sign, it worked!  Thanks a lot!